# How can I gather a list of cell contain a certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I need to search my entire worksheet a certain word and fill a column (B-in this case) contain the same word from column A without that specific word (in this case the word `Photo`). For example:

```
        A                 B
1   Photo Leon      |   Leon
2   Video Raul      |   Kelie
3   Broadcast Noa   |
4   Photo Kelie     | 
5   Video Carl      |
6   Broadcast Eitan |
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try (adjust `A$1:A$100` to suit):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$100,SMALL(IF(LEFT(A$1:A$100,6)="Photo ",ROW(A$1:A$100)),ROW(B1))),""),"Photo ","")
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and copied down until the first blank cell appears.

You might want to replace `Photo` with a parameter. Say enter `Photo` in D1 and instead:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$100,SMALL(IF(LEFT(A$1:A$100,LEN(D$1))=D$1,ROW(A$1:A$100)),ROW(B1))),""),D$1,"")
```

Comment: thanks. it worked on a single row. is there a way to make it work on an entire worksheet? I need to search the entire worksheet for a certain word and make a row contain the text that is in those cells

Comment: thank you both.
I managed to work something out with pnuts answer
but could make Garys answer to work. could you tell me more on how to make it work? dont know much scriptting

Answer (score 0):

Try this rather small macro:

```
Sub FindPhoto()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim ary, K As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Text
        If InStr(v, "Photo") > 0 Then
            ary = Split(v, " ")
            Cells(K, "B").Value = Trim(ary(1))
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]